# Node.js Mongoose.js string to ObjectId function

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

Is there a function to turn a string into an objectId in node using mongoose? The schema specifies that something is an ObjectId, but when it is saved from a string, mongo tells me it is still just a string. The _id of the object, for instance, is displayed as `objectId("blah")`.

Answer (score 570, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('4edd40c86762e0fb12000003');
```

Comment: Yeah that's a bit cleaner in this case. May only need to use the mongo.BSONPure if doing fromTime()

Comment: Does this throw an error if it's an invalid string?  Looking for the best way to do input validation in a REST API for mongo id fields.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question because using this methodology the string will be converted and not be the same as the original.

Comment: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) but my id is undefined then what it will return ? new id or error

Comment: @KevinDente I'm using Nodejs with Typescript, i've tried your solution but still getting a string and my query does not return what it should return. any idea on how to do it on typescript ?

Comment: Need to add, the string you pass must follow mongoose conventions, otherwise you'll get this error: `Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters`. In other words, you CAN'T do this: `var mongo_id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('blah')`

Comment: What happens if I do ```var id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('4edd40c86762e0fb12000003');``` (added ```new```) ? seems to work the same... but why?

Comment: Seems to work with common js require but using es6 `import mongoose from 'mongoose';` doesn't seem to work. `Argument of type 'import("mongoose").Types.ObjectId' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("mongoose").Schema.Types.ObjectId'.`. Anybody else gettting this?

Comment: Doesnt this generate a new ObjectId and not actually turn a string into a ObjectId?

Comment: Seconding @Stretch0. Does not work with es6 and typescript.

Comment: Does this work? var id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('4edd40c86762e0fb12000003');

Comment: Hello, to avoid the error when using import mongoose from mongoose, You can try with const id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('4edd40c86762e0fb12000003'), because seems to be a Class not a method

Comment: @MartinMuñoz I am facing the same problem. I have tried ```const id = new mangoose.Types.ObjectId("string")``` but my problem is-- it populates an ObjectId with a *new* keyword in front. Is there any way to remove the *new* keyword from the result?

Comment: I dont understand what you wanna do. The fix that I described is for compatibility issues between ES6 and CommonJS (basically it uses different ways of importing modules and syntax). Please provide some code and more detailed explanation of that you wanna achieve

Answer (score 29):

You can use this also

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
const _id = ObjectId("4eb6e7e7e9b7f4194e000001");
```

it's simplest way to do it

Answer (score 12):

You can do it like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var _id = mongoose.mongo.BSONPure.ObjectID.fromHexString("4eb6e7e7e9b7f4194e000001");
```

EDIT: New standard has fromHexString rather than fromString

Comment: Well, even more "new" standard is seems to be mongoose.mongo.BSONPure.ObjectID.createFromHexString()
(as of mongoose 3.9.7)

Comment: For those who are attempting to do this, this is a much better answer than the selected answer because it will not transform the id if you are already using a mongo id.

Comment: This no longer works, use the accepted answer instead

Comment: BSONPure isn't a part of `mongoose.mongo` for me. Can anybody confirm?

Answer (score 10):

For new versions, adding 'new' keyword to the selected answer worked, like this

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var _id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("64b0ee2c189286a5abc6b4ba");
```

Answer (score 9):

Judging from the comments, you are looking for:

```
mongoose.mongo.BSONPure.ObjectID.isValid
```

Or

```
mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var _id = mongoose.mongo.ObjectId("4eb6e7e7e9b7f4194e000001");
```

Comment: Could you comment on the difference between `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` and `mongoose.mongo.ObjectId`?  The object properties of mongoose are different, but they may be referencing the same method underneath.  Please comment on the underlying methods on `Types` vs `mongo`.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't resolve this method (admittedly I didn't search for long)

```
mongoose.mongo.BSONPure.ObjectID.fromHexString
```

If your schema expects the property to be of type ObjectId, the conversion is implicit, at least this seems to be the case in 4.7.8.

You could use something like this however, which gives a bit more flex:

```
function toObjectId(ids) {

    if (ids.constructor === Array) {
        return ids.map(mongoose.Types.ObjectId);
    }

    return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(ids);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just see the below code snippet if you are implementing a REST API through express and mongoose. (Example for ADD)

```js
....
exports.AddSomething = (req,res,next) =>{
  const newSomething = new SomeEntity({
 _id:new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(), //its very own ID
  somethingName:req.body.somethingName,
  theForeignKey: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.theForeignKey)// if you want to pass an object ID
})
}
...
```

Hope it Helps

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use schema

```
const yourSchemma = new Schema({
"customerId": {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Types;

const id = ObjectId('4edd40c86762e0fb12000003');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ObjectId a lot and don`t want to use mongoose.types.ObjectId, you can destructure your declaration:

```
const {
  Types: { ObjectId: ObjectId },
} = require("mongoose");

const id=ObjectId("4edd40c86762e0fb12000003")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am providing a chunk of code which is working. I am using mongoose( version ^7.4.0), typescript and node.js( version 16.16.0). I use Object
const sSchema = new Schema({  "Cell Phone": String, "Work Phone": String });

```
 const servicesModel = mongoose.model('Services', sSchema);

 const objectId = Object("63aed3cc10149ed38f1a24c0");
 servicesModel.find({ "_id" : objectId}).then(async (locationService) => {
 console.log(locationService);
});
```