# Mongoose String to ObjectID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have string with ObjectId .

```
var comments = new Schema({
    user_id:  { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users',required: [true,'No user id found']},
    post: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'posts',required: [true,'No post id found']}....

export let commentsModel: mongoose.Model<any> = mongoose.model("comments", comments);
```

*How i user it:*

```
let comment = new commentsModel;
str = 'Here my ObjectId code' //
comment.user_id = str;
comment.post = str;
comment.save();
```

When I create a "comment" model and assign a string user_id value or post I have an error when saving. I make `console.log(comment)` all data is assigned to vars.

I try:

```
 var str = '578df3efb618f5141202a196';
    mongoose.mongo.BSONPure.ObjectID.fromHexString(str);//1
    mongoose.mongo.Schema.ObjectId(str);//2
    mongoose.Types.ObjectId(str);//3
```

1. TypeError: Object function ObjectID(id) {
2. TypeError: Cannot call method 'ObjectId' of undefined
3. TypeError: Cannot read property 'ObjectId' of undefined

And of course I included the mongoose **BEFORE ALL CALLS**

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
```

nothing works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js Mongoose.js string to ObjectId function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578178/node-js-mongoose-js-string-to-objectid-function)

Comment: No methods from that question helps (

Comment: Then start showing some code / error messages which should be included in your question right from the start. We cannot help you when you don't show what fails (your code) and how it fails (the error)

Comment: I show code and sample of string

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You want to use the default export:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
```

After that, `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` will work:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
console.log( mongoose.Types.ObjectId('578df3efb618f5141202a196') );
```

**EDIT:** full example (tested with `mongoose@4.5.5`):

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var comments = new Schema({
    user_id:  { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users',required: [true,'No user id found']},
    post: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'posts',required: [true,'No post id found']}
});

const commentsModel = mongoose.model("comments", comments);

let comment = new commentsModel;
let str = '578df3efb618f5141202a196';
comment.user_id = str;
comment.post = str;
comment.save().then(() => console.log('saved'))
              .catch(e => console.log('Error', e));
```

Database shows this:

```
mb:test$ db.comments.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("578e5cbd5b080fbfb7bed3d0"),
    "post" : ObjectId("578df3efb618f5141202a196"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("578df3efb618f5141202a196"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: when i create "comments" model and set value i have error.
`comments.user_id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('578df3efb618f5141202a196');`

`message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "user_id"',
     name: 'CastError',
     type: 'ObjectId',
     value: '',
     path: 'user_id'`
Mongoose see empty field... ((((

Comment: That's a different issue (although `comments` is a schema in your example code, yet you're using it as a document?). Can you show how you create a model from the schema, how you create the document, and how you are assigning the `user_id` to it (all by editing your question)?

Comment: add some details to question

Comment: @Melixion `comments` is a schema, so `new comments` should fail already. It doesn't look like the actual code that you're using.

Comment: forgot some details ) you are right ) add to question

Comment: @Melixion I added a fully working example (for me) using your code.

Comment: How its possible ? ( `comment.user_id = str;` without `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` i have error (((

Comment: @Melixion which version of Mongoose are you using? `npm ls mongoose` should show you.

Comment: mongoose@3.8.40 ...
sudo npm install mongoose... and i see you version is higher, i will try and answer about it. You can help how to install latest version of mongoose?

Comment: @Melixion `npm install mongoose@latest`

Comment: this help, thinks!

Comment: I want to add that the value that you pass to this function must follow the convention for creating model ids, otherwise you will get this error... `Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters`

Comment: @AlecDonaldMather in fact, it must be a valid string representation of an ObjectId :D

Comment: This works for saving, but not for reading the object back in. It will still be an objectID and not a string using `find`

Answer (score 7):

use this

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var str = '578df3efb618f5141202a196';
 var mongoObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(str);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using TypeScript:

```
const Types = require('mongoose').Types
```

Then:

```
comment.user_id = new Types.ObjectId(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short code.

```js
const { Types } = require('mongoose');
const objectId = Types.ObjectId('62b593631f99547f8d76c339');
```

Comment: how would you do it with import statement instead of require?

Comment: @AlexBarbu import { Types } from 'mongoose';