# Mongo DB.find returning empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this line of code

```
    const comments = await db.Comment.find({post: req.params.post_id});
    return res.status(200).json({comments});
```

The request is being sent to the back-end successfully but the comments response is an empty array

```
/*
  res code: 200
*/

{
 comments: []
}
```

I checked other DB functions and they all work fine like adding a comment, editing it etc

my comment collection looks like this

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"605d1faeb202e4425c004be9"},"text":"Welcome to this comment","user":{"$oid":"5ff5d878dd830142686b7fd5"},"post":{"$oid":"6016f770ea76030d24688f89"},"createdAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1616715694247"}},"updatedAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1616715694247"}},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}


--------------------------------------------------------
{"_id":{"$oid":"605d1fb8b202e4425c004bea"},"text":"Welcome to this comment2","user":{"$oid":"5ff5d878dd830142686b7fd5"},"post":{"$oid":"6016f770ea76030d24688f89"},"createdAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1616715704381"}},"updatedAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1616715704381"}},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
```

I am trying to search by post id which is saved as post in my comment Collection

Comment: `req.params.post_id` is a string, the `post` field is an ObjectId.  See [Mongoose String to ObjectID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446346/mongoose-string-to-objectid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to wrap `req.params.post_id` in ObjectId.

Like this

```js
const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

const comments = await db.Comment.find({
   post: new ObjectId(req.params.post_id)
});
```

Comment: ```Mongoose: comments.find({ 'post.$oid': '6059444e21d546156cfce227' }, { projection: {} })```  still doesn't work

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: Or still an empty array?

Comment: empty array was returned

Comment: I think you need to wrap `req.params.post_id` in ObjectId. Try my updated answer