# Update or push in an array mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Sorry for my bad english i'm french and I do my best for speak english !
This is my issue:
I have a model **User** .

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    links: [{user_id: Schema.ObjectId,value: Number}],
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
},{
    strict: true
});
```

I want to make links between users in my nodejs app. For this I want to search for a link :

if it exist: update the value of this link

if not: create a new link

**My solution**

```
var link = {
    user_id: req.body.user_id,
    value: req.body.value
};
User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id, 'links.user_id': link.user_id}, {
            $set: {
                'links.$.value': link.value
            }
        },
        {safe: true, upsert: true},
        (err, user) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if(!user){
                User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{
                    $push:{
                        links:link
                    }
                },
                {safe: true, upsert: true},(err,user) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    return res.send('relation créé')
                })
            }
            res.send('Relation mise à jour!');
        }
    );
```

My solution give me this **error**:

```
    F:\Projets\the_one_panel\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:461
        throw err;
        ^
MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.
    at F:\Projets\the_one_panel\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:580:63
    at authenticateStragglers (F:\Projets\the_one_panel\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:503:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (F:\Projets\the_one_panel\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:539:5)
    at emitMessageHandler (F:\Projets\the_one_panel\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:309:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (F:\Projets\the_one_panel\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:452:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:597:20)
```

How to do what I want to do ? Thank's in advance for anwers !

Comment: Which exact value is in your `link.user_id`variable?

Comment: Edited; I have miss this :     
    var link = {
        user_id: req.body.user_id,
        value: req.body.value
    };

Comment: You are probably missing a conversion here, I suppose. Something like this to convert your id into an `ObjectId`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578178/node-js-mongoose-js-string-to-objectid-function

Comment: That's what I thought but it makes the same error: `user_id: require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId(req.body.user_id)`

Comment: Try replacing `findByIdAndUpdate` with `findOneAndUpdate`.

Comment: i got the same error

Comment: Ok news : The update work but the push seems to don't work. 
The error happend when the relation don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed:
@dnickless gave me the solution I need:
Swap to this code :

```
var link = {
    user_id: require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId(req.body.user_id),
    value: req.body.value
};
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id, 'links.user_id': link.user_id}, {
        $set: {
            'links.$.value': link.value
        }
    },
    (err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(user);
        if(!user){
            User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{
                $push:{
                    links:link
                }
            },
            {safe: true, upsert: true},(err,user) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.send('Relations créé');
            });
        }
        else{
            res.send('Relations mise à jour');
        }
    }
);
```

Remove `{safe: true, upsert: true}`
and replace `findByIdAndUpdate` with `findOneAndUpdate`