# How to fix "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm not able to get data from mongodb. When i run server it is showing error like this :

> node:15171) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to
>   ObjectId failed for value "${this.groupId}" at path "_id" for model
>   "Group"

```
    export const getGroup = async (req, res) => { 
        const {groupId} = req.params;

        if (!groupId) { 
            return res.status(400).json({ 
                error: true, 
                message: 'You need to provided a group id' 
            }); 
        }

        // Search for see if group exist 
        const group = await Group.findById(groupId);

        if (!group) { 
            return res.status(400).json({ 
                error: true, 
                message: 'Group not exist' 
            }); 
        }

        try { 
            return res.status(200).json({ 
                error: false, 
                meetups: await Meetup.find({ group: groupId }).populate('group', 'name')
            }); 
        } catch (e) { 
            return res.status(400).json({ 
                error: true,
                message: 'Cannot fetch meetup' 
            }); 
        } 
    };
```

Comment: please post the group and meetup schema also.

Comment: import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const GroupSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    minLength: [5, 'Name must be 5 characters long'],
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minLength: [10, 'Description must be 10 characters long'],
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
  },
  meetups: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Meetup',
  }],
}, { timestamps: true });

Comment: GroupSchema.statics.addMeetup = async function (id, args) {
  const Meetup = mongoose.model('Meetup');
const meetup = await new Meetup({ ...args, group: id });
  const group = await this.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $push: { meetups: meetup.id } });
  return {
    meetup: await meetup.save(),
    group,
  };
};

export default mongoose.model('Group', GroupSchema);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js Mongoose.js string to ObjectId function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578178/node-js-mongoose-js-string-to-objectid-function)