# query working in mongoshell but not in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

Hi below is the description of the issue i am facing
**mongoShell query**

```
db.masters.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
               _id: ObjectId("5e2554ec3405363bc4bf86c0")
            }
        }, {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'masters',
                localField: 'mappedVendors',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'mappedVendors'
            }
        }, { $unwind: '$mappedVendors'}, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$mappedVendors" } },
        { 
           $lookup:
            {
                from: "orders",
                let: { mappedVendorId: "$_id" },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$orderCreatedBy", "$$mappedVendorId"] } }
                    },
                    { $project: { orderCreatedOn: 1, isApproved: 1 } }
                ],
                as: "orders"
            }
        },{
           $lookup:
            {
                from: "payments",
                let: { mappedVendorId: "$_id" },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$paymentDoneBy", "$$mappedVendorId"] } }
                    },
                    { $project: { outstanding: 1 } }
                ],
                as: "payments"
            }
        },
        { $project: { name: 1, phoneNo: 1, address: 1, depotCode: 1, orders: 1, payments: 1 } }
    ]).pretty()
```

**response i am getting in mongoshell**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e2555643405363bc4bf86c4"),
        "phoneNo" : 9992625541,
        "name" : "vendor4",
        "address" : "4 vendor address 4",
        "depotCode" : "D3139",
        "orders" : [ ],
        "payments" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5dd7aa6c31eb913a4c4a487c"),
                        "outstanding" : 300
                }
        ]
}

    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e2555783405363bc4bf86c5"),
            "phoneNo" : 9992625542,
            "name" : "vendor5",
            "address" : "5 vendor address 5",
            "depotCode" : "D3139",
            "orders" : [
                    {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5e2564323405363bc4bf86c6"),
                            "isApproved" : false,
                            "orderCreatedOn" : ISODate("2020-01-20T08:26:26.812Z")
                    },
                    {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5e27fd3da42d441fe8a89580"),
                            "isApproved" : false,
                            "orderCreatedOn" : ISODate("2020-01-15T18:30:00Z")
                    }
            ],
```

This query in shell is working as expected in shell but when i am trying this in nodejs its returning empty[].
below is the description of my nodejs file
**1: Mongodb Connection string**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/#####App', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify:false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
```

**NOTE:** ##### is not my code
**2:nodejs controller**

```
exports.vendorWiseIndent = async (req, res) => {
const { dealerId } = req.body
try {
    const order = await Master.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(dealerId)
            }
        }, {
            $lookup: {
                from: "masters",
                localField: "mappedVendors",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "mappedVendors"
            },
        },
        { $unwind: "$mappedVendors" }, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$mappedVendors" } },
        {
            $lookup:
            {
                from: "orders",
                let: { mappedVendorId: "$_id" },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$orderCreatedBy", "$$mappedVendorId"] } }
                    },
                    { $project: { orderCreatedOn: 1, isApproved: 1 } }
                ],
                as: "orders"
            }
        }, {
            $lookup:
            {
                from: "payments",
                let: { mappedVendorId: "$_id" },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$paymentDoneBy", "$$mappedVendorId"] } }
                    },
                    { $project: { outstanding: 1 } }
                ],
                as: "payments"
            }
        },
        { $project: { name: 1, phoneNo: 1, address: 1, depotCode: 1, orders: 1, payments: 1 } }
    ])


    console.log(order)
    return res.status(200).json({
        order
    });
} catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
}}
```

**I have also tried it with just {_id: dealerId}**
**3"nodejs router file**

```
router.post("/vendorwiseindent", vendorWiseIndent.vendorWiseIndent);
```

**POSTMAN BODY & url**

```
POST: http://localhost:5002/vendorwiseindent
{
    "dealerId": "5e2554ec3405363bc4bf86c0"

}
```

**POSTMAN RESPONSE:**

```
{
    "order": []
}
```

**I have also tried it with just{ _id: dealerId}**
now mongodb database contains multiple collections and i have already other API's running so the db which is connected is right,there has to be some other issue that this query is not working in nodejs or rather its returning an empty array as order:[] but the query is working in shell 
 **"mongoose": "5.7.4" & mongodb version is 4.2**

Comment: Please tell me mongoose version?

Comment: @Mahesh Bhatnagar its  "mongoose": "5.7.4" & mongodb version is 4.2 u r ryt this info should be in my question i have also edited that in my question

Comment: Please do `console.log(dealerId)` before query & post what you get here

Comment: i have found out the issue i had forgotten const mongoose = require('mongoose ') hence dealerId was not getting converted to objectID

Answer (score 0):

**nodejs controller files need be checked**,
**ADD**

```
`const mongoose = require('mongoose ')`
```

**at the top**
dealerId was not getting converted to objectID as it was missing, **after its addition POSTMAN response is** mentioned below:

```
{
"order": [
    {
        "_id": "5e2555643405363bc4bf86c4",
        "phoneNo": 9992625541,
        "name": "vendor4",
        "address": "4 vendor address 4",
        "depotCode": "D3139",
        "orders": [],
        "payments": [
            {
                "_id": "5dd7aa6c31eb913a4c4a487c",
                "outstanding": 300
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e2555783405363bc4bf86c5",
        "phoneNo": 9992625542,
        "name": "vendor5",
        "address": "5 vendor address 5",
        "depotCode": "D3139",
        "orders": [
            {
                "_id": "5e2564323405363bc4bf86c6",
                "isApproved": false,
                "orderCreatedOn": "2020-01-20T08:26:26.812Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e27fd3da42d441fe8a89580",
                "isApproved": false,
                "orderCreatedOn": "2020-01-15T18:30:00.000Z"
            }
        ],
        "payments": []
    }
]
```

}