# Mongoose $in operator only updating one document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having trouble with the "$in" operator in Mongoose. At a high level I have a User schema, and one of the fields is an array of a Card schema. Within the Card schema there is a 'score' field. I would like to update the 'score' field based on a list of Card ids. Here is what I am trying to use:

```
User.updateMany(
  {
    "_id": userId,
    "cards._id": {
      "$in": cardIds
    }
  },
  { $inc: {"cards.$.score": 1 }},
  (err) => {console.log(err)}
)
```

When I run this code, only the first Card in the `cardIds` array is updated instead of all of them. Any idea why this isn't working? Thanks.

Comment: did you tried `cards.score`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, it throws an error. Without the $ it seems to be trying to create a new field called 'score'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use arrayFilters in [.updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#db.collection.updateMany) , Try this query :

```
User.updateMany({
    "_id": userId
},
    { $inc: { "cards.$[element].score": 1 } },
    { arrayFilters: [{ "element._id": { "$in": cardIds } }] },
    (err) => {}
)
```

Comment: Tried this, but I'm not seeing any changes in my db. No errors, though...

Comment: @Evan : Is that updating earlier ? Did you check types being sent in input & in DB match ?

Comment: The original version was updating the first card in the array. So that led me to believe my array of ids was the right types. It's an array of strings, if that helps.

Comment: And specifically, for my test, I'm using 4 ids:  [ '5e45a85418385d873b412115', '5e45a86c18385d873b412119', '5e569fff9cb91a0017bc2dbe', '5e456f6c30fd19843048fc8b' ]

Comment: @Evan : Are those `cards._id`'s strings in DB & also did you convert  `userId` to `ObjectId()`?

Comment: No, in the db they are MongoDB objectIds.

Comment: I did not convert userId to ObjectId(). I haven't needed to in other queries, so I didn't think that was necessary.

Comment: @Evan : not sure how it worked but in general you need to convert strings to `ObjectId()`'s & pass those in query. Check :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578178/node-js-mongoose-js-string-to-objectid-function , unless types do match updates don't work..

Comment: Thanks, I made the change to the types, but it still doesn't appear to be making any of the updates.

Comment: Added a callback for err as the last input and it worked. Thanks!