# Unable to add a object as a Sub field for another Existing JSON object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am unable to add the following object:

```
[
    { 'option1':'opt1','option2':'opt2','option3':'opt3'},
]
```

as a sub filed to:

```
const question_list=await Questions.find({ $and: [{categoryid:categoryId},{ isDeleted: false }, { status: 0 }] }, { name: 1 });

question_list=[{"_id":"5eb167fb222a6e11fc6fe579","name":"q1"},{"_id":"5eb1680abb913f2810774c2a","name":"q2"},{"_id":"5eb16b5686068831f07c65c3","name":"q5"}]
```

I want the final Object to be as:

```
[{"_id":"5eb167fb222a6e11fc6fe579","name":"q1","options":[
    { 'option1':'opt1','option2':'opt2','option3':'opt3'},
]},{"_id":"5eb1680abb913f2810774c2a","name":"q2","options":[
    { 'option1':'opt1','option2':'opt2','option3':'opt3'},
]},{"_id":"5eb16b5686068831f07c65c3","name":"q5","options":[
    { 'option1':'opt1','option2':'opt2','option3':'opt3'},
]}]
```

what is the best possible solution?

Comment: Are these objects : `[{"_id":"5eb167fb222a6e11fc6fe579","name":"q1"},{"_id":"5eb1680abb913f2810774c2a","name":"q2"},{"_id":"5eb16b5686068831f07c65c3","name":"q5"}]`  inside an array of a document ? Or documents itself ?

Comment: yes that object is a MongoDB response of a find query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) to do this, instead of `.find()`. As projection in `.find()` can only accept `$elemMatch, $slice, and $` on existing fields : [project-fields-from-query-results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#project-fields-to-return-from-query). So to add a new field with new data to documents, use `$project` in aggregation framework.

```
const question_list = await Questions.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [{ categoryid: categoryId }, { isDeleted: false }, { status: 0 }]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: 1,
      options: [{ option1: "opt1", option2: "opt2", option3: "opt3" }]
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KeBalqDaDzj)

Comment: I am getting the options field added,but the match operator is not working I am getting null set even I am Having matching Data

Comment: @AbhinavV : Using playground link can you give me sample docs & input, let's try like that !!

Comment: Surprisngly ur query answer was working in mongoplayground but im unable to use the same code in nodejs
https://mongoplayground.net/p/_WJGsFZjpc_

what could be the error

Comment: @AbhinavV : that I'm not sure, try to debug by printing incoming request, One common mistake usually people is with type match, Let's say if `categoryid` is of type `ObjectId()` & input will usually be string then it doesn't get you anything as there is type mismatch, So you need to convert string to ObjectId() prior to querying..

Comment: yes that was the issue,So is there any built in mongoose method to convert a string to ObjectId()

Comment: @AbhinavV : Check this : (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578178/node-js-mongoose-js-string-to-objectid-function)