# $and Query not able to search on two columns

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a dataset like this:

```
{
 page1: ["login", "registration"], // Here multiple pagename will store
 page2: ["5c35f1045643180d9488221f"] // Here Multiple id will store
},
{
 page1: ["login", "registration"],
 page2: []
}
```

So on my data query I want to get data in which page1 === "login" and page2 === "5c35f1045643180d9488112f".

So I tried to get this through $and query but I am not getting anything.

My code is this:

```
db.collection.find(
 {
  $and: [
    {page1: {$in: ["login"]}},
    {page2: {$in: ["5c35f1045643180d9488221f"]}}
  ]
 }
)
```

I don't know where I am doing mistake. Kindly suggest me if I am wrong or wrote the wrong statement on query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578178/node-js-mongoose-js-string-to-objectid-function . You need to check type of inputs does match with type of field values in DB or not, If your `page2` field is of type `ObjectId()` in DB then you need to convert input from string to `ObjectId()` in code & hit the query..

Answer (score 0):

[edited]
Try

```
db.collection.find({page1: "login", page2: "5c35f1045643180d9488221f"})
```

if this does not work, the value is wrong. check the value of page 2 again

Comment: same result. i.e empty data.

Answer (score 0):

If page2 is an array of `ObjectIds` not `strings`, then you may use something like that

```
db.collection.find({
  page1: "login",
  page2: ObjectId("5c35f1045643180d9488221f")
})
```

you can test it here [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rKqnuKu4BQ9)

hope it helps