# MongoDB Different result using .findOneAndUpdate() vs .updateOne nested in findOne

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I'm not sure why the removal doesn't work using the latter method. (`foundList` is not `null`)

Latter method:

```
    List.findOne({name: listType}, function(err, foundList){
      if (err){
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        foundList.updateOne({}, { $pull: { item: { _id: itemID } } });
        console.log('deletion success');
        res.redirect("/" + listType);
      }
    });
  }
```

Schema:

```
const itemSchema = {text: String}
const listSchema = {  
  name: String,
  item: [itemSchema]
}
```

Comment: You get different result for `findOneAndUpdate` and `updateOne` is because `findOneAndUpdate` will return old document if option `{ new: true}` is not passed as third argument to the API.

Answer (score 1):

Below line is wrong and wont work. This is because `foundList` contains [result of the query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#executing) `findOne`.

```
foundList.updateOne({}, { $pull: { item: { _id: itemID } } });
```

After you call `List.findOne({name: listType}, function(err, foundList)`, `foundList` contains result of the query, and you cannot call any query/mongoose-api on that. You need to call mongoose APIs like `updateOne` on the model object, only then you will get the result.

What you can do is you can modify that document and then save it. You can do that like this:

```
List.findOne({name: listType}, function(err, foundList){
      if (err){
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        let index = foundList.findIndex((list: any) => list.item._id == itemID );
        if (index !== -1) {
            foundList.splice(index, 1);
        }
        foundList.save().then(()=>{
            console.log('deletion success');
            res.redirect("/" + listType);
        })
     }
})
```

Or you can do all that in one query. Try this:

```
List.findOneAndUpdate({name: listType}, {
   $pull: {
       item: { _id: itemID } 
   }, {new:true})
.then((response) => {
   console.log('deletion success');
   res.redirect("/" + listType);
})
.catch((err) => res.json(err));
```

**NOTE**: Also make sure `itemID` is of type `ObjectId` and not `string`. You can typecast `string` to `ObjectId` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578178/node-js-mongoose-js-string-to-objectid-function).