# Deleting all records when trying to delete single row in Node express mongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I am showing data of several users in my application where there is a functionality of edit and delete of individual record.I am using Node express framework and using MongoDb as a database.My problem is when I am deleting any specific record then all the records are deleting from the table and when I am showing the result in console it is showing only that record on which I intended to delete.

Below is my code:

**index.ejs**

```
div class="container">

 <% if(users.length>0) {%>

    <p>Total available users - <%= users.length  %> </p>

   
      <table class="table">

        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope="col">City</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>


        <tbody>
         <%  for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++) { %>
           <tr>
            <td><%= users[i].name %></td>
            <td><%= users[i].email %></td>
            <td><%= users[i].city %></td>
            <td><a href="/edit/<%= users[i]._id %>">Edit</a> | <a id = "del" href="/delete/<%= users[i]._id %>"> Delete </a> </td>
           </tr>
         <% }  %>  
        </tbody>
      
      </table>

  
  <% } else{ %>

     <p>No data found</p>
 <%  }  %>  

</div>
```

This yields below ui:

[image]

**Student.js Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  name:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  email:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  city:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  timeCreated:{
    type:Date,
    default:()=>Date.now()
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Student',studentSchema);
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Student = require('./models/Student');
const dotEnv = require('dotenv').config();
const cors =  require('cors');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.use("/public", express.static('public')); 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

app.get('/delete/:id',(req,res) => {

mongoose.connect(process.env.URI,{useNewUrlParser:true,
        useUnifiedTopology:true}).then(() =>

            Student.findOneAndDelete(req.params.id, (err,result) => {

                if(err){
                    console.log("Error",err);
                }
                else{
                    res.redirect('/');
                    console.log(result + " - " + req.params.id);
                }
            })
         
         ).catch((err) => console.log(err));

});

app.listen(port,() => console.log(`App is running at ${port}`));
```

Someone let me know why all the records are deleting instead of one which I want to delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongoose offers two similar methods: [findOneAndDelete](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-findoneanddelete-function/) which takes JavaScript object representing query as first parameter or [findByIdAndDelete](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-findbyidanddelete-function/) which can take `ObjectId` as first parameter. Therefore you can change your code into:

```
Student.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id }, (err,result) => {
```

or

```
Student.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, (err,result) => {
```

Also make sure that types match - if `req.params.id` comes as string and you store your ids as `ObjectId` then you need to convert them (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578178/node-js-mongoose-js-string-to-objectid-function)).

Answer (score 0):

can you try **delete** request instead of **get**

```
app.delete('/delete/:id',(req,res) => {
mongoose.connect(process.env.URI,{useNewUrlParser:true,
useUnifiedTopology:true}).then(() =>

        Student.findOneAndDelete({_id: req.params.id}, (err,result) => {

            if(err){
                console.log("Error",err);
            }
            else{
                res.redirect('/');
                console.log(result + " - " + req.params.id);
            }
        })
     
     ).catch((err) => console.log(err));

});
```

```html
<td><a href="/edit/<%= users[i]._id %>">Edit</a> | <form action="/delete/<%= users[i]._id %>" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= users[i]._id %>"/>
  <button>DELETE</button>
</form></td>
```