# Updating value in a nested document in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```js
const itemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    checkedValue: String
});

const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    items: [itemsSchema]
});
```

I want to update data like this: `listSchema`>`items`>`checkedValue`. I have performed the following operation:

```js
db.collections.update({
  "name": "Home"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "items.$[i].checkedValue": "On"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "i.items._id": ObjectId("646ec7836f8ba817e80e3372")
    }
  ]
})
```

But I am getting an error `no document found`. How can I update the specific document?

Sample data:

```js
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("646ec7916f8ba817e80e3377"),
    name: 'Home',
    items: [
      {
        name: 'home 1',
        checkedValue: 'Off',
        _id: ObjectId("646ec7966f8ba817e80e3380")
      },
      {
        name: 'home 2',
        checkedValue: 'Off',
        _id: ObjectId("646ec79a6f8ba817e80e338c")
      },
      {
        name: 'home 3',
        checkedValue: 'Off',
        _id: ObjectId("646efd38b1bc960c52ce5078")
      }
    ],
    __v: 3
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("646ed4136f8ba817e80e339b"),
    name: 'School',
    items: [
      {
        name: 'School 1',
        checkedValue: 'Off',
        _id: ObjectId("646efd45b1bc960c52ce509c")
      },
      {
        name: 'School 2',
        checkedValue: 'Off',
        _id: ObjectId("646efd4cb1bc960c52ce50a9")
      },
      {
        name: 'School 3',
        checkedValue: 'Off',
        _id: ObjectId("646efd52b1bc960c52ce50b1")
      }
    ],
    __v: 4
  }
]
```

Comment: It is because the objectId:646ec7836f8ba817e80e3372 you search for in items , is not in the name:Home document

Answer (score 1):

the object id you gave in the array filter is not in the items list. anyway even if it did the way you have written `arrayFilters` has to be changed to `i._id`. Think of `i` as an individual element in the `items` array

```js
db.collection.update({
  name: "Home"
},
{
  $set: {
    "items.$[i].checkedValue": "On"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "i._id": ObjectId("646ec7966f8ba817e80e3380")
    }
  ]
})
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nEGdKaThSug)

Comment: It works fine at the link you have provided. But maybe it's deprecated now. So, I am getting an error. Alternatively I have tried to use ```List.collection.findOneAndUpdate({name:listName},{$set:{"items.$[i].checkedValue":"Off"}},{arrayFilters:[{"i._id":checkedItemId}]}); ```. But the value is not updating.

Comment: Hi which update method did you use. updateone? Update many? Is your model List. If so shouldn't it be list.update?

Comment: I have tried both ```updateOne()``` and ```findOneAndUpdate()``` method. My model name is ```List```. I have tried using ```List.collection.findOneAndUpdate()``` and ```List.findOneAndUpdate()```. But, the value is not changing. Thanks.

Comment: btw which mongodb version are you using. also which mongoose version

Comment: mongodb: 5.5.0,
        mongoose: 7.2.0

Comment: Not really sure why it isn't working maybe try going through GitHub issues? https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues?q=Arrayfilters+

Comment: Actually I am taking the value for the ```arrayFilter``` by ```const checkedItemId = req.body.checkedItemId;```. The ```req.body``` part send me back the id as an string. Should I convert it to an ObjectId before passing it to the ```arrayFilter```? I have tried that also by ```const checkedItemId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.checkedItemId)``` but it popoulates an ObjectId with a **new** keyword in front. Which may be not equal to the original `_id` saved in the database. Is there any way to remove the new keyword from the front?

Comment: yes! you need to cast it to an ObjectId. don't use new https://stackoverflow.com/a/8393613/13583510

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your written query is incorrect as my perspective. Because you have used **db.collections.update({ }). In here, it should be db.collection.update({ })**

After that, to perform the query you need to write it as,

```
arrayFilters: [
    {
      "i._id": ObjectId("646ec7966f8ba817e80e3380")
    }
  ]
```

Then your first index item will be updated.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. ```update``` is deprecated now. So it is not recognized. Rather I have tried this ```List.collection.findOneAndUpdate({name:listName},{$set:{"items.$[i].checkedValue":"Off"}},{arrayFilters:[{"i._id":checkedItemId}]});```. But the value is not updating.

Comment: @Fahad If it was deprecated, you can find another solution from [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html)

Answer (score 0):

When sending value to the `arrayFilter`, I have to convert the `_id` to an `ObjectId`. This is done by the following code:

```js
const checkedItemId = req.body.checkedItemId;
const checkedItemObjectId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(checkedItemId);
```

And to update the value in the subdocument, the following `updateOne()` method worked fine for me:

```js
                List.collection.updateOne(  
                    { 'items.checkedValue': 'Off' },
                    { '$set': { 'items.$[element].checkedValue': 'On' } },
                    {
                      arrayFilters: [
                        {
                          'element._id': { '$eq': checkedItemObjectId }
                        }
                      ]
                    })
```