# Mongoose query to get an inner array and a specific element from that inner array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to retriev an array from a mongoose schema usging the aggragate function fron mongoose. I am using nestjs for this project, but the queries are the same:

```
const notifications = await this.userRepo.aggregate( [
      { $match: { _id: userId } },
      { $unwind: "$notifications" },
      { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$notifications' } }
] );
```

The problem here is that every time I am getting an empty array. No matter what is inside the document.

Here is a document example:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6471fe4a0045e48a0c6193ba"),
  gateways: [
    {
      _id: '5231db1f-b79a-4dc3-a387-6f08ad7b6857',
      name: 'Babylon Dev',
      right: 'owner'
    }
  ],
  __v: 0,
  notifications: [
    {
      type: 'confirm',
      title: 'Gateway whitelist request!',
      description: '6471fe4a0045e48a0c6193ba wants to share data from gateway 5231db1f-b79a-4dc3-a387-6f08ad7b6857 with you.',
      actions: [Array],
      from: '6471fe4a0045e48a0c6193ba',
      subject: '5231db1f-b79a-4dc3-a387-6f08ad7b6857',
      status: 'unread',
      _id: new ObjectId("64b6791adbf7bb6eaa528cf2")
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone clue me in where am I setting this up wrong?

The result that I want is to get the notifications array:

```
[
    {
      type: 'confirm',
      title: 'Gateway whitelist request!',
      description: '6471fe4a0045e48a0c6193ba wants to share data from gateway 5231db1f-b79a-4dc3-a387-6f08ad7b6857 with you.',
      actions: [Array],
      from: '6471fe4a0045e48a0c6193ba',
      subject: '5231db1f-b79a-4dc3-a387-6f08ad7b6857',
      status: 'unread',
      _id: new ObjectId("64b6791adbf7bb6eaa528cf2")
    }
  ]
```

Also it would help to get/update/delete one element inside the `notifications` array.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/DCTRRh4-dCR  make sure your `userId` is not a string but type ObjectId

Comment: Yeah...that was it... Thanks man. Lay down an answer so I can recommand it, please! Thanks!

Comment: sure i posted with an alternate as well

Comment: Could I bother you for another question on mongoose/mongodb? This is a little strange and I need a quick solution.

Comment: can have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254545/discussion-between-andy95-and-cmgchess).

Comment: I started a chat for this.

Comment: hi you could ask a new question since then someone else might be able to answer if i couldnt. i think that would be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the `userId` is the same type as what is stored in the database. In your case it is an `ObjectId`. you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578178/node-js-mongoose-js-string-to-objectid-function) how to do it.
[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DCTRRh4-dCR)

```js
const notifications = await this.userRepo.aggregate( [
      { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId )} },
      { $unwind: "$notifications" },
      { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$notifications' } }
] );
```

or you can go the long way without using the utility functions :P
[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yx9XA7orIbs)

```js
const notifications = await this.userRepo.aggregate( [
      { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$_id", { $toObjectId: userId } ] } } },
      { $unwind: "$notifications" },
      { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$notifications' } }
] );
```