# How to check if each values in array exist in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Simply, I am working on a project and I faced a case and want to know if I am implementing it correctly.

I expect the client to send an array of IDs, and I need to check if each value in the array exists or not in the database. If any value does not exist, I will send a response with an error. Otherwise, I will proceed with the next actions.

I have implemented the idea in the following way:

```
let result = null;

for (let i = 0; i < listIds.length; i++) {
    const existCheck = await branchModel.exists({ _id: listIds[i] }) != null ? true : false;

    if (existCheck == false) {
        result = false;
    }
}

if (result != false) {
    result = true;
}

return result;
}
```

However, I think this approach may impact performance if the array is very long, and I am not sure if calling the database multiple times in the same API is healthy and not expensive.

Is there a method in Mongoose to achieve the same idea?

**Soluation :**

```
let result = false;

let unique = [...new Set(listIds)];

const branches = await branchModel.find().where('_id').in(unique);
        
if(branches.length === unique.length){
    result = true;
}
else{
    result = false;
}
        
return result;
```

Thanks aneroid & jQueeny

Answer (score 2):

Yes that will impact performance because as [per the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.exists()):

> Under the hood, MyModel.exists({ answer: 42 }) is equivalent to MyModel.findOne({ answer: 42 }).select({ _id: 1 }).lean()

So if `listIds` is a long array then you are doing a `findOne` once per each item in the array so that is one database call per array item.

I have had to do something similar like this in the past and if you are only concerned with knowing that at least one `_id` is not there and not necessarily worried about which one then you can just get all documents with an `$in` and then comparing the length of the `listIds` with the length of the documents. Given that `_id` is unique, if they don't match then at least one is not there.

```js
const docs = await branchModel.find({ _id: { $in: listIds } } );
return docs.length === listIds.length;
```

Or with using mongoose Query Builders:

```js
const docs = await branchModel.find().where('_id').in(listIds);
return docs.length === listIds.length;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`countDocuments`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.countDocuments()) in Mongoose and filter by the `_id`s in `listIds`.

If the count of docs is not the same as the length of the list, then one or more objectIDs were missing. Add a step to [make `listIds` unique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/1431750). Otherwise, `["aaa", "aaa", "aaa"]` would give an error since you'd get back only one document for one `"aaa"`, ie count=1 even though the input was 3.

```js
var listIds = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];
let uniqueIds = [...new Set(listIds)];

const existsCount = await branchModel.countDocuments({ _id: { $in: uniqueIds } });
return existsCount === uniqueIds.length;
```

<strike>And if listIds is are, [convert them to `ObjectIDs`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8393613/1431750) before doing `countDocuments`.</strike> *Edit: [This conversion is not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77634426/how-to-check-if-each-values-in-array-exist-in-database/77634568?noredirect=1#comment136866185_77634568) since mongoose will do that automatically.*

Note: It's probably be better to use `find + length` as per jQueeny's answer since it would use the index on `_id`. But for countDocs:

> If you call `countDocuments({})` , MongoDB will always execute a full collection scan and **not** use any indexes.

Comment: I like the `new Set(listIds)` to remove erroneous duplicates from the user. If `_id` is an `ObjectId` then mongoose will cast the `listIds` strings for you. If one isn't castable it will throw a `Cast to ObjectId failed` error. Very helpful.

Comment: @jQueeny _If `_id` is an `ObjectId` then mongoose will cast the `listIds` strings for you._ Oh, I didn't know that, thanks! (I don't use mongoose or node, and barely know js). But the _check in list of IDs_ method is such a common pattern across so many databases, collection types, etc. it was hard to not provide an answer with the obvious way :-)